# Is there a way to derive a flow type from an object type, making optional properties not optional?

Tags: flowtype

Given some type containing optional properties:

```
type Obj = {
  a: string,
  b: ?string,
  c?: string,
  d?: ?string,
  e: ?string | void,
}
```

I'd like to derive a new type from this such that it has the same properties, but not optional.

```
type Obj = {
  a: string,
  b: string,
  c: string,
  d: string,
  e: string,
}
```

I thought that `$ObjMap` plus `$NonMaybeType` would do this for me:

```
type SafeObj = $ObjMap<Obj, <T>(T) => $NonMaybeType<T>>;
```

However, I've found that it doesn't work for cases `c` and `d` above, where a `?` was put on the property's key to make it optional.

Is there any other way to accomplish what I need that will support optional properties?

Are there any other differences between putting a `?` on the key vs putting `void` as an option on the value side?

[Here is a complete try-flow example](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AeQEYBWoAvKAN6KigCGAXKAM4oBOAlgHYDmANFaPgYB+Zu259qAYyENRnXvwAmM0CNbyJoLMLndQAH1AA3WG0V8AvsnTZQAZRqQsBYmQAkLgLI0MAHhc8oL4AKgB8ABTBAJSkoaBuAHKwHN5o+FjBmFghoaEA3MiSycygKFjMDA5OLqSg4eQWDDQcaFEFiCCgAJJaAB7Ykii00NCgsJClABblOCiwoBg0jIylWaCS05IA1vKo5SgAdDQHc3bq3OFRe8wH+CewZ2Jcl9eHkveP8i9lN4of588rj9Dlh-k9LkA)

Comment: I doubt that this is what you're looking for, but if your object type in question really only has one value type then this will work: https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AeQEYBWoAvKAN6KigCGAXKAM4oBOAlgHYDmANFaPgYB+Zu259qAYyENRnXvwAmM0CNbyJoLMLndQAH1AA3WG0V8AvsnTZQAZRqQsBYmXKgA1AG0AJAGksNEYAHhcAPgBdBh8AOVgOAFkaNHwsABVMLGCfADUaaABXLBDwsIsAbmRJeOZQFGKUBgcnF1JQAApyCwYaDjQASkrEEFAASS0AD2xJFFpoaFBYSDqAC2KcFFhQDBpGRjrM0Ek1yQBreVQGgDoaK827dW52-svmK-w72AexLmfXlCukk+33kf3qb0UwMevxe4IBWChP2eQA